# Set up grub2 on cloned Ubuntu installation

Tags: 10.04, grub2, clone

With an Ubuntu Live Disc, I have copied my Ubuntu 10.04 installation to a new harddisk (with the same hardware). However, it doesn't boot, since I think I still need to set up grub for this new installation.
How do I set up grub2 for a copied Ubuntu installation?
All the tutorials for grub2 didn't really help me...

running

```
update-grub
```

on the "original" Ubuntu installation doesn't find the copied Ubuntu installation.

Comment: How exactly did you clone the Ubuntu installation?

Comment: I used gparted from a Ubuntu 10.10 live disk. In gparted, you can "copy/paste" a whole partition.

Comment: I'd have used clonezilla http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php , another solution is while booted in live mode, mount your partition by either clicking on it in nautilus or `sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt` (replace X with partition number) and from terminal do `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda` reboot into installed ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB#Methode-2-root-directory-Variante) is the solution I used... It's in german, unfortunately.

It's basically the same as described in the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2?action=show&redirect=GRUB2#Copy_LiveCD_Files):

1. In a Live-CD session run: `sudo fdisk -l` to determine the disk name X and the partition number Y of your Ubuntu installation - should be of form `/dev/sdXY`.
2. run `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`
3. run `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX`
4. Reboot.
5. Update the grub menu: `sudo update-grub`

Comment: helpful to many, perhaps, but the post is asking for help with grub2, not grub (grub-install is a tool for grub, not grub2)